# Return Dictionary in using str in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bank account OOP project I am working on. And I can't seem to figure out this one bug. In brief, I would like to return a users bank account after they have added it. I have included all the code because I've solved this in an object-oriented way. The str() method seems to be the problem.

```
from enum import Enum
class AccountType(Enum):
  SAVINGS = 1
  CHECKING = 2

class BankAccount():

  def __init__(self, owner, accountType):
    self.owner = owner
    self.accountType = AccountType(accountType)
    self.balance = 0

  def withdraw(self, amount):
    if amount > self.balance:
        raise Exception('Your balance is' + self.balance + 'cannot take this much money!')
    else:
        self.balance -= amount

  def deposit(self,amount):
    self.balance += amount

  def __str__(self):
    return "Owner: {}. Account type is: {} ".format(self.owner, AccountType(self.accountType).name)

  def __len__(self):
    return self.balance


#This class is responsible for returning information about the user and their account type. 
class BankUser():

  #initialize an accounts dictionary. 
  accounts = {}
  def __init__(self, owner):
    self.owner = owner

  def addAccount(self, accountType):
    if self.accounts.get(accountType) != None:
        raise Exception('Cannot have more than 1 ' + AccountType(accountType).name + ' account!')
    self.accounts[accountType] = BankAccount(self.owner, accountType)

  #test if user inputs an account, otherwise throw an error
  def getBalance(self, accountType):
        return len(self.accounts[accountType])


  def deposit(self, accountType, amount):
        if (accountType in self.accounts and isinstance(self.accounts[accountType], BankAccount)):
            self.accounts[accountType].deposit(amount)
        else:
            raise Exception(self.owner + ' does not have a ' + AccountType(accountType).name + ' account!')


  def withdraw(self, accountType, amount):
    self.accounts[accountType].withdraw(amount)

  def __str__(self):
     return "Your account is {}".format(AccountType(accountType).name)

user = BankUser("David")
user.addAccount(1)
print(user)

#OUTPUT
TypeError: __str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'accountType'
```

I would like to return a users account. How do I do that? Everything I have tried has ended up with this error.

Comment: I believe the problem is that `accountType` is undefined in your `__str__()` method. You need to extract the account type from your dictionary of accounts.

Comment: `AccountType(accountType).name` isn't syntactically correct anyway. What are you trying to print there?

Comment: Typically, you use `__str__` to return some human-friendly representation of the class instance itself. You don't use it for general messages.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to move the accounts dictionary to be owned by a single bank user instance, not the bank user class (move to the `__init__`)

Then, all your methods have `accountType` except `__str__`, so you cannot just access it as a variable, but you could return the whole dictionary instead.

```
class BankUser():

  def __init__(self, owner):
    self.owner = owner
    #initialize an accounts dictionary. 
    self.accounts = {}

 ...

 def __str__(self):
   return "Accounts: {}".format(self.accounts)
```

Or you can do `[AccountType(type).name for type in self.accounts]`

Comment: Is there a way for it to return the type of account? e.g SAVINGS or CHECKINGS?

Comment: You have multiple accounts for a BankUser, what do you mean?

Comment: So the output to the code you've suggested is: ``` Accounts: {1: <__main__.BankAccount object at 0x10f033898>}```

Comment: Looks like your `__str__` on the BankAccount class is not being called. Or you actually need to define `__repr__` for it as well, but as I mentioned below the code, you're welcome to iterate over the accounts and get the types